# How can I align the top navigation bar completely to the top left?

Tags: html, css

I am having a hard time getting rid of the small white layer to the left and top of the navigation bar I have. I circled it in the picture. Any ideas? Thanks. Im assuming that it has to do with where I deal with the ul css but I could be wrong.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pretty-checkbox@3.0/dist/pretty-checkbox.min.css">
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

i {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 30;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(20, 24, 29);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav  {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav  {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Kitting Center</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Config Master <i class="arrow down"></i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="Option1">Option 1</a>
          <a href="Option2">Option 2</a>
        </div>
      </li>
  <li><a href="/add">Firmware Rename</a></li>
  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="pretty p-default p-curve">
            <input type="radio" name="color" />
            <div class="state p-primary-o">
                <label>ISP</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="pretty p-default p-curve">
        <input type="radio" name="color" />
        <div class="state p-success-o">
            <label>MPISP</label>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>


<div class="main">
    <h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
    <p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the image that shows the white space that I would like to get rid of.
[image]

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We'll also need your HTML

Comment: ok give me 30 seconds

Comment: usually to fix this, I would do this in css: `html { margin: 0; padding: 0}`

Comment: May you copy-paste all of your code into the post or in a codepen so we can test this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the css to

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following styles to your CSS which will remove the spacing:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you were late to the party or you just copy/pasted the previous answer.

Comment: @EternalHour look at the timestamp of both answers before commenting ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I did, they are 1 min apart.

Comment: @EternalHour I'd assume we were both typing the same answer at the same time.  I also commented with this solution 24min ago.

Comment: @EternalHour this one was posted first so how can the copy/past occur?

Comment: @TemaniAfif it could occur by copying from my comment on the post

Comment: Could be, doesn't change the fact that there are 2 identical answers :)

Comment: @EternalHour identical or not, you should not  *accuse* him for copying .. anyway, the question is an nth-duplicate and this answer was provided a million time before

Comment: @TemaniAfif My bad, I misinterpreted the timestamp, you're right. It was not meant to be an accusation in the first place. But as you said, it's a duplicate anyway.